# What is this huge hole in my back yard?? Can I fill it in?

Tags: pipe, sewer

I have a huge hole “ maybe 3 foot diameter and 8ft deep” I have noticed the ground sinking in around it. I would like to fill it in. I know that around 12 years ago we went from septic to public sewers. [image]

Comment: You're asking random strangers what to do with your yard based on that tidbit of information? o_O It looks like a septic access, but who knows from here?

Comment: Even though i feel like your comment was to make me feel dumb. That is exactly what it is. I had no idea what to even search or call it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My comment was to prompt you to provide more information. Imagine being in our shoes. Who's going to suggest major excavation of your property based on what you've provided?